# Problem from baby Rudin about completion of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $C[X]$ the set of all Cauchy sequences in $X$.

Call two $\{p_n\},\{q_n\}\in C[X]$ *equivalent* if $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}d(p_n,q_n)=0$. This is an equivalence relation.

Let $X^*$ be the set of all equivalence classes so obtained, define $d^*(x^{*},y^{*})=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,y_n)$ where $x^{*},y^{*}\in X^{*}$ and $x_n\in x^{*},y_n\in y^{*}$. And this is well-defined and it's a metric in $X^{*}$.

For any $p\in X$ we associate $p^{*}\in X^{*}$ which contains a constant Cauchy sequence $(p,p,\cdots)$. Hence we have function $T:X\to W\subset X^{*}$. This map is surjective, i.e. $T(X)=W$ and also is isometry.

We can check that $W$ is dense in $X^{*}$ and $(X^{*},d^{*})$ is a complete metric space.

This is problem from baby Rudin. And also there is a last problem in chapter 3.

What is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$? (Compare with above exetcise).

I know that $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. Can any explain this to me?

Comment: What is baby Rudin?

Comment: If you apply this procedure on $\mathbb Q$ you would get exactly $\mathbb R$. This (partially) due to the fact that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rationals.

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Comment: @QuangHoang, but how realize this procedure to $\mathbb{Q}$? I did this but any results. It turns to nonsense.

Comment: You should note that $\mathbb{R}$ is not the only completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore some arguments are needed to proof this. You could for example show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with this metric. The result follows from that.

Comment: The definition says that two Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb Q$ are equivalent if and only if they have the same limit (in $\mathbb R$). That means two elements of $\mathbb Q^*$ are the same if they define the same limit in $\mathbb R$. That should give you a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb Q^*$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Without this construct you might not have $\mathbb R$ anyway, so you have to have another definition for $\mathbb R$ then and it would not be the same as $\mathbb Q^*$, but isomorphic to it. Exactly what is it you want to get explained?

Comment: @Marc, I Know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and also can prove that fact.

Comment: @QuangHoang, diffeomorphism is not defined in Rudin. You wrote " if they have the same limit (in $\mathbb{R}$)". Why $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: diffeomorphism = isomorphism + distant preserving. Also $\mathbb R$ because it is *the* completion of $\mathbb Q$ with respect to the usual metric (different metrics give different completions).

Comment: How to prove this strictly? that reals are completion of rationals. Also i can't find solution anywhere.

Comment: I think you should review completion and try to *actually* solve this problem. This is, like @skyking said, another definition of $\mathbb R$. And what it asks is to show the equivalence of two definitions (i.e. diffeomorphism).

Comment: After  you  found  $T$  is  surjective  ,  you say  $T(X)=W$ .  But $W$  is  not  predefined, what  is  $W$?

Comment: @user118494, With each $b\in X$ we associate the class $b^*\in X^{*}$ which contains the constant Cauchy sequence $(b,b,...)$. This defines a mapping $T:X\to W\subset X^{*}$. Understand?

Comment: No  I  don't  understand. Not   the  mapping , my  problem  was  the  subset  $W$ . What  does  $W$  look  like  as    set$?$ Do  you  mean  $W$=$\{b^{*} \in X^{*} |\{b\}  is  a  constant  sequence \}$  and  then  map $X$  into  $W$  via  $T$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ you can do the following. It follows by this fact that any Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ has limit in $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. We therefore "identify" an equivalence relation of Cauchy sequences with their common limit point in $\mathbb{R}$ which means that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}^*\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ we know that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is complete $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Q}^* = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q^{*}}$ questioning me. Because elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ are points but elements of $\mathbb{Q^*}$ are sequences. Can you explain that moment please?

Comment: To compare it with your notation. In this case we write $\mathbb{Q}$ for the space $X$. In your text you write about the isometry $X\rightarrow W\subset X^*$. That isometry should answer your question.